# Sorting names and storing them to an Array cell with LinkedList

Tags: java, arrays, singly-linked-list

So the idea is to get an input which is a `String`(a name to be specific), then store it in an `Array` with the size of 26 to its respective cell. The sorting goes this way: names that start with 'A' goes to cell 0, names that start with 'B' goes to cell 1 and so on. Now, a cell contains a `LinkedList` where the names are sorted again alphabetically.

So far, the approach I made is by using the switch case.

```
private void addDataAList(AuthorList[] aL, String iN) {
    char nD = Character.toUpperCase(iN.charAt(0));
        switch(nD){
            case 'A':
                AuthorList[0] = iN;
            break;

            case 'B':
                AuthorList[1] = iN;
            break;
            //and so on
        }
}//addData
```

is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried `AuthorList[nD - 'A'] = iN;`?

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon no, and thank you. I didn't even know you could do it this way.

Comment: But you need to somehow protect from ArrayOutOfBoundException. For example catch it and throw new IllegalArgumentException with appropriate message about requirement of capital first letter. Also iN.trim() may be useful.

Comment: @MariuszSzurgot will do, as soon as I get to the point where I add finishing touches to the code.

Comment: This is typically an XY problem. What do you exactly need? Implementing a dictionary (as in a list of existing words, not a map)? Check something like a [trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie).

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon this one begins with 'so' !!

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire to sum it up, what I exactly need is to find a way to store an object called AuthorList(which uses the data structure LinkedList) to its corresponding cell.

Comment: You mean AuthorList extends LinkedList or have field of LinkedList in it?

Comment: have a field, sorry for being vague there.

Comment: Ok, I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that AuthorList class may look like this:

```
private class AuthorList{
    private LinkedList<String> nameList;

    public AuthorList() {
    }

    public AuthorList(LinkedList<String> nameList) {
        this.nameList = nameList;
    }

    public LinkedList<String> getNameList() {
        return nameList;
    }

    public void setNameList(LinkedList<String> nameList) {
        this.nameList = nameList;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("AuthorList{");
        sb.append("nameList=").append(nameList);
        sb.append('}');
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

I'd make it like this:

```
private static void addDataAList(AuthorList[] aL, String iN) {
    int index = Character.toUpperCase(iN.trim().charAt(0)) - 'A';
    try {
        AuthorList tmpAuthorList = aL[index];
        if(tmpAuthorList == null) aL[index] = tmpAuthorList = new AuthorList(new LinkedList<>());
        if(tmpAuthorList.getNameList() == null) tmpAuthorList.setNameList(new LinkedList<>());
        tmpAuthorList.getNameList().add(iN);
    } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException aioobe){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Name should start with character A - Z");
    }
}
```

And additional main method for test purposes:

```
public static void main (String[] args){
    AuthorList[] aL = new AuthorList[26];
    addDataAList(aL, " dudeman");
    for (AuthorList list : aL) System.out.println(list);
}
```

Comment: List is not a generic iirc or is that supposed to be ArrayList? either way, I'll try to model my code with yours and see if it works before I can accept this as an answer.

Comment: I was not sure what AuthorList is and how add data to it, but i'm sure assigning String to AuthorList[x] with '=' will fail so I've changed it to make it working properly for testing purposes. Of course you should fit this solution to your needs with AuthorList class.